# Load balancer Path Based Routing

Tags: 301-redirect, amazon-aws

I have example.com/blog currently hosted on Amazon. I created a path based redirect to blog.example.com in Load Balancer Listner.

How can I put variables in the redirection or if we can use regex?  For instance, example.com/blog/date/content -> blog.example.com/blog/content.

I can't use .htaccess because I'm trying to shutdown example.com/blog.  Any help would be great!  Thank you.

Thank you.

Comment: Are you using AWS CloudFront?

Comment: No, currently not using CloudFront.